# adding array of days in a calendar rows/columns

Tags: javascript, html

I'm buliding a web calendar with plain javascript and I'm stuck on displaying numbers in the `<td></td>` and stop them after 7 columns.

Until now I have all the data I need but I can't display them how I want in the HTML.
My problems are:

- I keep creating just one `<tr></tr>` instead of 6 (maximum of weeks in a month)
- I display the numbers after my `<tr><td></td></tr>` instead of inside.

I think this is mostly a matter of how to insert an element into the HTML. Any suggestion is really appreciated.

Code:

```
 window.wca = {};

(function() {
    wca.today = new Date();
    createCalendar();

function createCalendar(){
    wca.currentYear = wca.today.getFullYear();
    wca.currentMonth = wca.today.getMonth(); //month in number
    wca.currentDayOfWeek = wca.today.getDay();
    wca.firstDay = new Date(wca.currentYear, wca.currentMonth, 1); //first day of current month
    wca.firstDayOfWeek = daysLabel[wca.firstDay.getDay()]; // first dayOfTheWeek of current month
    wca.showMonth = monthNamesArray[wca.currentMonth]; //current month string
    wca.showWeekDay = daysLabel[wca.currentDayOfWeek]; //current day of the week
    wca.totDayInMonth = daysPerMonth[wca.currentMonth]; //how many days are in the current month

    //Leap years
    if (wca.currentMonth == 1) { // February 
        if((wca.currentYear % 4 == 0 && wca.currentYear % 100 != 0) || wca.currentYear % 400 == 0){
          wca.totDayInMonth = 29;
        }
    }

    var Htmltable = document.getElementById('table');
    var year = document.getElementById('year');
    var month = document.getElementById('month');
    var daysOfWeek = document.getElementById('days-of-week');


    year.innerHTML = '<td>'+ wca.currentYear +'</td>';
    month.innerHTML = '<td>'+ wca.showMonth +'</td>';
    for(i = 0; i < daysLabel.length; i++)
        daysOfWeek.innerHTML = daysOfWeek.innerHTML + '<td>'+ daysLabel[i] +'</td>';

    Htmltable.innerHTML += '<tr id="days-row">';
    var daysRow = document.getElementById('days-row');

    var day = 1;
    for(i = 1; i <= 6; i++){ //weeks in a month (rows)
        for(j = 0; j <= 6; j++){ //7 days in a week (coloumns)
            daysRow.innerHTML += '<td>'; 
            if(day <= wca.totDayInMonth){
                daysRow.innerHTML += day;
                day++;
            }
            daysRow.innerHTML += '</td>';
        }
        //if day > totDayMonth - stop making line 
    }  
    Htmltable.innerHTML += '</tr>';

}
})();
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody id="table">
        <tr id="year"></tr>
        <tr id="month"></tr>
        <tr id="days-of-week"></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: which month has six weeks??? you haven't assigned an id to the table.. what is daysRow? what is wca?

Comment: Any month can have 6 weeks... Except february i guess...

Comment: One week has 7 days (atleast in the world where i live) and one month has maximum 31 days.. 31/7 => 4 weeks. Where do you live?

Comment: i'm sorry but is not exactly like that since some month have days start at half of the week and/or finish i.e on monday. that mean, you have 4 to 6 row in a graphical representation of your calendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really difficult to guess what's the issue there without more complete example.
One thing that could be the reason is empty cells which are collapsing. Also I've moved the innerHTML to html variable which is appended just once..

to compensate that try this code which is adding a non breaking space to empty cells:

```
var Htmltable = document.getElementById('table');
var day = 1;
var html = '';
    for(i = 1; i <= 6; i++){ //weeks in a month (rows)
        html += '<tr>';
        for(j = 0; j <= 6; j++){ //7 days in a week (coloumns)
            html += '<td>'; 
            if(day <= wca.totDayInMonth){
               html += day;
                day++;
            } else {
                html += "&nbsp;";
            }
            html += '</td>';
        }
        //if day > totDayMonth - stop making line 
       html += '</tr>';
    }  
    Htmltable.innerHTML += html;
```

Comment: what is daysRow? what is wca? which week has 6 months?? better understand the problem first before coming up with a solution!

Comment: Really ? .. It's true what they say about critics.. it's far more easy to make a critics than propose a solution and work together to help the people

Comment: i am trying to work together in the comment section under the question.. When you post an 'Answer' it means this is the solution to your problem.. which your solution clearly isn't. You are giving an opinion which you can in the comments section but not like, here.. this is the answer to your question.

Comment: Ok .. I don't discuss this kind of things here, we will see if this helped or not

Comment: Hey @Goran.it thanks for your answer, I posted the whole code, seems to be better, sorry i just tried to keep focus where the problem is.

Comment: So following your examples i can see now all my numbers in a td, which is good! But they are still display in 1 big row instead to break it after 7 days

Comment: Oh, I've updated the code to enclose each week in single row .. try it now, it should be ok

Comment: Yeyy!! Yes now it work! So they main problem was where to insert the <tr> and <td>. Nice now i know how to insert element without innerHTML property :) thank you very much